# "anymore" vs. "any more"

Tags: grammaticality, differences, orthography, confusables, spacing

> any more requests
>
> anymore requests

Are these two the same? It seems that "any more requests" is grammatically correct while "anymore requests" is not. Am I right? Why are they different?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`anymore` is used, when you compare the *status quo* to the *status quo ante*: Something that was does no longer apply to the *status quo*, but it was thus earlier.

For instance:

> I can't take it anymore.

Previously, you didn't very much or it just didn't bother you. But now, it has become too much to bear, and you cannot continue like that any longer.

`any more` are two words, where you can take the meaning of each word quite literal and it refers to more of something than you currently have/want.

In a question:

> Are there any more surprises

You would be wondering, if there are additional surprises - thereby implying that there were already some.

> anymore requests

I can't think of an example where this would be grammatically correct.

> any more requests

This is correct.

Comment: _Any more_ in the sense you describe is a Negative Polarity Item. That's why its occurrence is limited.

Comment: *Anymore* as one word (even in "I can't take it anymore") is not standard British English; that sentence would be "I can't take it any more"). Just as "I can't imagine it becoming one word anytime soon" is not standard British English either.

Answer (score 14):

As this NGram shows, the single-word form is a relatively recent innovation...
[image: .]

If in doubt, put the space in. I can't think of any sentence where that would actually be considered incorrect by anyone. But as OP indicates, there are definitely contexts where most if not all native speakers would object to the single-word form.

I don't really think it makes much sense to claim different meanings for the two forms, <strike>but [here](http://alt-usage-english.org/anymore.html)'s someone making a good stab at it.</strike>

---

EDIT: (Many years later! :)

I just found [this site](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UPCunTN6eP4C&pg=PT44&dq=%22anymore%20or%20any%20more%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4xuu7-P3ZAhUSZFAKHdUKDZkQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22anymore%20or%20any%20more%22&f=false), which says ***Anymore*** means at the present time, any longer, or from now on, whereas ***Any more*** means anything or something additional or further.

They also say ***Anymore*** is not normally considered an actual word in UK English, which explains my earlier position. But older and wiser, I can see the point of the distinction...

> 1:) *I have enough staff. I don't need to hire **anymore**.*  (continued hiring is unnecessary)
>   2:) *I have enough staff. I don't need to hire **any more**.* (more staff are unnecessary)

Comment: +1, very nice ngram; note etymonline says: "one-word form by 1877"

Comment: I don't think an nGram is relevant here: both of these are valid expressions, they just mean completely different things.

Comment: If you look at the actual uses of *any more* before 1960, a substantial fraction of them would be spelled *anymore* today. I believe the Ngram is actually telling us something, even though the one-word *anymore* has been around since the late 1800s.

Comment: I think some people would like to tease out one very restricted meaning (something like hereafter/henceforth) and say that's the single-word version. I included a link to an attempted differentiation, but at the end of the day I don't buy the idea that *only* the single-word form is valid in certain contexts. I think the NGram is telling us something though - that an increasing number of people lately are moving in that direction.

Comment: If you type “I can’t take it any more.” into Microsoft Word, it says “Possible Word Choice Error” and suggests “anymore”.  (***I*** ignore the suggestion and leave it as two words.)

Comment: That only covers the spelling. The actual negative polarity term is much older, and whether or not it's spelled with a space has nothing to do with its age or correctness,

Comment: I like the staff example.

Answer (score 6):

I wonder if it could be a US x UK issue. I have always learnt and used 'any more' (two words) in all contexts, and come from a British family unit, attending a British School.
So we would have:
John doesn't live here any more (UK)
John doesn't live here anymore (US)

Comment: Yes, I believe this is a US / UK difference. I've never seen any Brit use the one-word form "anymore" (except for when MS Word's grammar checker has "corrected" it, IMHO incorrectly).

Answer (score 3):

They are very similar, but there is one difference:

> Are there any more guests coming? The boat can't stand the weight anymore.

*Any more* is used to mean "additional", while *anymore* means 'any longer'

As you can see, there are instances when *any more* needs to be used to clarify from *anymore*.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the second example, "anymore requests" is incorrect because *anymore* is an adverb. According to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anymore), *anymore* carries a negative connotation, too, and also can mean "nowadays" in a non-negative way. I have heard it used that way here in SE USA.

For the negative connotation see also: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THtX7H6ZJi8

Comment: But "any more" is also an adverb - http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/any_more

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, that is right, but in the first example it is only "any" that is the adverb (modifying "more" which is an adjective modifying "requests").

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ginger Software's list of words that commonly cause confusion](http://www.gingersoftware.com/english-online/spelling-book/confusing-words/any%20more-anymore),

> **Any more**
>
> Definition:
> adjective any (negative) + adverb (quantity) more; or additional spelling of anymore
>
> Example:
> I don't need *any more* clothes.
>
> ---
>
> **Anymore**
>
> Definition:
> no longer; (usually used with a negative)
>
> Example:
> Alice doesn't live here *anymore*.